# Blender for Engineering: Numbering and naming objects in blender

Tags: add-on, workflow, measurement

I am working on technical drawings with Blender using MeasureIt. I am following  for making blueprints of specifical parts [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb1U7g4JFbA), and it works great.
 But when I am producing "big picture" drawings where I want to show the numbering and naming of different parts -which I'll produce blueprints of-  of e.g. a motor, I have to do it in PowerPoint. But this I think is a bit shabby. I wonder if there's a way of doing it in Blender?

I'm thinkink about something in this fashion, with a legend:

[image]

Comment: Can you share images to illustrate what you can do and what you want to do?

Comment: My advise would be to render a clean image in blender and add the numbering later in inkscape, illustrator or other graphic design program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [grease pencils](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/grease_pencil/introduction.html) are inicially for. However, I don't think there is any way to type in text although there are some [addons](https://blendermarket.com/products/penciltext) (I never tried  this myself) and [discussions](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/4hbbbc/grease-pencil-text).

[image: grease pencil]

Comment: Maybe it's time for creating my first add-on then :-)